# A dual of the result " every finitely generated module over a commutative ring is Hopfian"

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, category-theory, modules, finitely-generated

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. We know then that any finitely generated $R$-module is Hopfian i.e. any surjective homomorphism from $M$ to $M$ is bijective ...

My question is: Is there any dual to the above statement ? Something like , is every finitely co-generated module co-hopfian (every injective endomorphism is bijective) ? Or some refinement of this ? I already know that Artinian modules are co-Hopfian so I would be wanting a possible refinement of that.

NOTE: In a dual sense, we do have the following result: If $M$ is torsion less i.e. the natural map $M \to M^{**}$ is injective and $M^*$ is Co-Hopfian, then $M$ is Hopfian ... unfortunately I doubt this is of any help towards the question I'm asking ...

Comment: What does "finitely cogenerated" mean?

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: finitely co-generated means for any collection of submodule whose intersection is $0$, you can find a finite sub collection whose intersection is also $0$ ... look here for other equivalent conditions https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_module

Comment: If this were true, I would imagine the proof would employ some kind of dual to Nakayama's lemma, which I think would be something like how finitely cogenerated modules must contain nonzero elements annihilating the jacobson radical... But since the Hopfian result is so ubiquitous, I guess if thie dual were true it would be easy to find a reference...?